# Pointer to MATLAB function?

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop, switch-statement

So I have a for-loop in MATLAB, where either a vector x will be put through one function, say, cos(x).^2, or a different choice, say, sin(x).^2 + 9.*x. The user will select which of those functions he wants to use before the for-loop.

My question is, I dont want the loop to check what the user selected on every iteration. Is there a way to use a pointer to a function, (user defined, or otherwise), that every iteration will use automatically?

This is inside a script by the way, not a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [function_handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html). For your example (to run on all available functions using a loop):

```
x = 1:10; % list of input values
functionList = {@(x) cos(x).^2, @(x) sin(x).^2 + 9*x}; % function handle cell-array
for i=1:length(functionList)
    functionOut{i} = functionList{i}(x); % output of each function to x
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to give an actual name to the functions instead of a list number?

Comment: Yes, you can set another cell with names (as strings), `functionName = {fun1, fun2}` and use a `switch`/`case` statement, or an `if/else` statement using `strcmp(userProvidedName, fun1)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the following:

```
userChoice = 2;

switch userChoice
    case 1
        myFun = @(x) sin(x).^2 + 9.*x;
    case 2
        myFun = @(x) cos(x).^2;
end

for k = 1:10
    x(k,:) = myFun(rand(1,10));
end
```

Comment: Thanks Muster, is this what is called an 'inline' function? Also, what if the function was more than just 1 line? No problem?

Comment: @Learnaholic: these are anonymous functions. If you need more than one line, you can write your function in an m-file like normal matlab functions.